# Swift Core data Error when trying to populate

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm new with swift and got a problem with core data.

My app crashes when trying to populate. I just have 1 field as for testing purposes

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    seedRestaurantList()
    fetch()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func fetch() {
    let moc = DataController().managedObjectContext
    let nameFetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "RestaurantList")

    do {
        let fetchedName = try moc.executeFetchRequest(nameFetch) as! [RestaurantList]
        print(fetchedName.first!.name!)

    } catch {
        fatalError("merda again: \(error)")
    }
}
func seedRestaurantList () {
    let moc = DataController().managedObjectContext


    let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("RestaurantList", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! RestaurantList

    entity.setValue("teste", forKey: "name")


    do {
        try moc.save()


    } catch {
        fatalError("deu merda: \(error)")
    }
}
```

}

This is the error that I get

> 2015-11-02 17:38:04.880 DinDins[2993:1252158] CoreData: error: Illegal
>   attempt to save to a file that was never opened. "This
>   NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores (unknown).  It
>   cannot perform a save operation.". No last error recorded. 2015-11-02
>   17:38:04.885 DinDins[2993:1252158] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This
>   NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores (unknown).  It
>   cannot perform a save operation.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x236c585b 0x3503adff 0x2346da89 0x2346dc95 0x2346de2d 0x2347710f 0x1249d03 0x12534fb 0x23468ef1
>   0x233b31f3 0x233b3223 0x233d615b 0x9cff0 0x9c360 0x9c400 0x277f9f55
>   0x278b6c4f 0x278b6b45 0x278b5ef1 0x278b5b27 0x278b577d 0x278b56f7
>   0x277f5cc3 0x270bdb05 0x270b9201 0x270b9091 0x270b85b1 0x270b8263
>   0x270b1a1f 0x23688091 0x23686387 0x235d90f9 0x235d8ecd 0x27867607
>   0x278622dd 0x9fde0 0x35788873) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Thanks in advance

---RestaurantList+CoreDataProperties.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension RestaurantList {

    @NSManaged var name: String?

}
```

---RestaurantList.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class RestaurantList: NSManagedObject {

// Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object subclass


}
```

Comment: Did you modify your existing Core Data structure?

Comment: just added RestaurantList+CoreDataProperties.swift and RestaurantList.swift

Comment: And you didn't add any new parameters to you MOCs?

Comment: no... Should I do that? and where? (sorry, really new to swift)

Comment: Did you created your app with adding "Core Data" activated?

Comment: This is not a swift problem. Please look on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075831/coredata-this-nspersistentstorecoordinator-has-no-persistent-stores-it-cannot. It may help you.

Comment: What is  `DataController`? The Core Data stack is supposed to work like a singleton. You're creating `DataController` instances at least two times which causes the error I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ricardo, try reseting your simulator. Open the Simulator, go to menu *Simulator* and select *Reset content and Settings*

Comment: I'm testing on iPhone. Should I avoid doing it?

Comment: delete your app and install again

Comment: I've deleted the project and created one from scratch and it worked, Thanks

Comment: Nice, every time u change your data model, u need reset your simulator.. or reinstall the app